In zsh, annotate each line in a file to which both stdout and stderr have been redirected with the line's source (stdout or stderr)
In zsh, how can I annotate each line in a file to which both stdout and stderr have been redirected with the line's source (stdout or stderr)?
I want output with the source name prepended to the line, like:
stdout: <a line written to stdout>
stderr: <a line written to stderr>


Related: Can I configure my shell to print STDERR and STDOUT in different colors?

Possible duplicate of How to capture ordered STDOUT/STDERR and add timestamp/prefixes? (though that one was for bash).

Redirect both stdout and stderr to process substitutions which will do the annotating, and the redirect the whole thing to the file:
{ some-command > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /') 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') } > some-file

If you have ts from moreutils, then it's a bit shorter:
{ some-command > >(ts stdout:) 2> >(ts stderr:) } > some-file


Though note that (depending on scheduling randomness and such), that might cause stdout and stderr lines to get reordered with respect to each other. No way around that, though.

@ilkkachu no way around that except maybe via some dirty code injection hacks such as the one used in Can I configure my shell to print STDERR and STDOUT in different colors?

@StéphaneChazelas, yep, exactly...
